# Interpreting the output of PHP's DateTimeZone::getOffset function

Tags: php

I am trying use PHP to calculate the number of seconds difference between two time zones. I'm pretty much copying the sample code directly from the PHP documentation at http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getoffset.php, but I'm getting the wrong answer (or at least not an intuitively correct answer). My code is:

```
$my_timezone = new DateTimeZone("America/New_York");
$server_timezone = new DateTimeZone("America/Denver");

$my_date = new DateTime("now", $my_timezone);
$server_date = new DateTime("now", $server_timezone);

var_dump($my_timezone->getOffset($server_date));
```

The output is `int -18000`, or -6 hours, but it should be +2 or +3, depending on daylight savings time. Not to mention, the example they give in the PHP documentation shows a seven hour time difference between Taipei and Tokyo, even though they're really one hour apart. Can someone please explain what's going on, and how can I find the correct time difference between two time zones? Thank you very much.

P.S. As long as I'm lost, what's the purpose of the line `$my_date = new DateTime("now", $my_timezone);`. `$my_date` is never referenced again in the code.

Answer (score 2):

`$my_timezone->getOffset($server_date)` returns the offset from GMT of `$server_date` using the offset rules for `$my_timezone`.  That's why you're getting a result you don't expect.

If you want to get the difference between two time zones using `getOffset()` you'll have to call `getOffset()` on both timezones and subtract one from the other.

```
<?php
$my_timezone = new DateTimeZone("America/New_York");
$server_timezone = new DateTimeZone("America/Denver");

$my_date = new DateTime("now", $my_timezone);
$server_date = new DateTime("now", $server_timezone);

$my_offset = $my_timezone->getOffset($my_date);
$server_offset = $server_timezone->getOffset($server_date);

$diff = $my_offset - $server_offset;    
var_dump($diff);
```

The above outputs 7200, which is the number of seconds in 2 hours, which is the difference between the time zones.

Comment: +1 thanks for clarifying, the PHP doc confuse me as well, they declare 2 sets of variables but used only part of each...